# Unable to type closing angle bracket in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

After messing with Keyboard settings and searching the net I haven't been able to find a solution. I am trying to include a header file in a program which is kinda hard if you can't close the angle brackets. Every time I try to type it a black rectangle shows up on my screen with a circle crossed through and it doesn't type the character. After trying all the other symbols on my keyboard, it seems this is the only one doing this.

I also used `showkey` to make sure it captured the key being pressed and it did.

```
keycode  42 press
keycode  52 press
keycode  52 release
keycode  42 release
```

I have a Vaio laptop and the keyboard is built in and my Input Source is English (US)

Comment: What type of keyboard have you actually got, and which one have you told your Linux system you're using?

Comment: @roaima I have a Vaio laptop and the keyboard is built in and my Input Source is `English (US)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, unbeknownst to me, there was a global keyboard shortcut mapped to `>` that wasn't working and that's why I would get that error message. I had to edit my shortcuts and take it off.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've resolved your specific situation,
but a partial solution to your general question is to type

```
printf "\076\n" | tee gt
```

This will create a file called `gt` that contains a `>` (greater-than symbol)
and a newline (and will also display those characters on the screen). 
You can then read that file into your source code file, and copy and paste.

You can use a similar technique to compensate
for the unavailability of the <kbd>></kbd> key when typing shell commands. 
If you want to run a command and redirect its output to a file, e.g.,

```
date > current_time
```

just do

```
date | tee current_time
```

If you don't like having the output come to the screen (in addition to going into the file), define this function

```
write_to()
{
    if [ "$#" = 0 ]
    then
        echo "Usage: write_to file ..."
        return
    fi
    tee "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

in your `~/.bashrc`, or wherever. 
It lets you type things like

```
date | write_to current_time
ps | write_to file1 file2
```

To get the effect of `>>`, write an `append_to` function that uses `tee -a`. 
And, going back to my very first command:
if, for some reason, the `printf` command isn't available, you can do

```
echo a | tr a "\076" | tee gt
```